# Searching during Pentaho ElasticSearch update runs

Tags: elasticsearch, pentaho

We are using ES to index ~1.5mil records from the database. To populate the index we are using Pentaho ES component which is set to “Overwrite if exists” (runs ~15 min). Also, individual indexed documents can be retrieved, updated or deleted via Java services.

The question is, what will ES return during full Pentaho update run? For example, we have 1.5mil indexed documents with version = 1. Next update will change this version to 2. If we request a document while Pentaho is updating it – will we receive the old version of it? Will service will be unavailable for that particular document? Also, if we receive an old version, will the new version be available immediately after update or will it wait till full batch is updated (pentaho component is sending rows in batches of 5k)?

Pentaho - 4.4

ElasticSearch - 0.19.4

Lucene - 3.6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You will receive the old version of a document if the new one isn't committed yet.  The service will continue to be available.
2. The new versions will be available depending on the `refresh_interval` setting in elasticsearch.  This defaults to every `1s`.

It's possible that pentaho may twiddle the `refresh_interval` during the data load.  If that's the case then you'll have to wait until pentaho calls the `refresh` method directly or until it resets the parameter.

You might simply start the run and then check the setting for the `refresh_interval` via:

```
curl -XGET "http://my-es-server:9200/my-index-name/_settings"
```